# Alert view controller not presented once API call successfully completed SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, api

I have the following API call:

```
    func updateSheetVals() {
        let args = ["id": viewModel.id]

        let measurements = UpdateRequest.Measurements(
             departure: Double(sheet.postRefuelQuantity.field.currentValue),
             discrepancy: Double(sheet.discrepancy.field.currentValue),
             discrepancyPercentage: Double(sheet.discrepancyPercent.field.currentValue),
             preTotal: Double(dheet.preTotal.field.currentValue),
             targetTotal: Double(fuelSheet.requiredTotal.field.currentValue)
        )

        let body = UpdateRequest(measurement: measurements)

        API.client.post(.updateFuelSheetVals, with: args, using: .put, posting: body, expecting: MessageResponse.self) { (success, response) in
            switch success {
            case .failure:
                print("Check network connection")
            case .success:
                DispatchQueue.asyncMain {
                    self.present(WarningViewController.finished(), animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And yet, even though I receive a 200 response and the API is called correctly, my view controller is never displayed. Happy to provide more contextual code if needed, but wondered firstly if I'm just missing something obvious with this block...

EDIT:

The API call is triggered in the following code:

```
   func acceptButtonPressed(_ button: Button) {
        var confirmation: UIViewController & ConfirmationAction

        guard let level = viewModel.getSelectedSheet().order.levelDouble else { return }

        if self.viewModel.requiresSignature {

            if level < 3 {
                confirmation = SignatureViewController(hasDiscrepancy: viewModel.hasDiscrepancy, discrepancyPrompt: viewModel.discrepancyPrompt, sl: level)
            } else {
                confirmation = SignatureViewController(hasDiscrepancy: viewModel.hasDiscrepancy,
                                                            discrepancyPrompt: viewModel.discrepancyPrompt, sl: level)
            }

        } else {
            if let userInputAllowed = sheet.userInputAllowed, level < 3, !userInputAllowed {
                confirmation = OrderAcceptAlertViewController.alert()
            } else if level < 3 {
                confirmation = DiscrepancyAlertViewController.alertWithDiscrepancy(hasDiscrepancy: viewModel.hasDiscrepancy,
                                                                                   discrepancyPrompt: viewModel.discrepancyFromManualInput(discrepancyValue: fuelSheet.percentageDiscrepancy.field.currentValue))
            } else {
                confirmation = DiscrepancyAlertViewController.alertWithDiscrepancy(hasDiscrepancy: viewModel.hasDiscrepancy,
                                                                                   discrepancyPrompt: viewModel.discrepancyPrompt)
            }
        }

        confirmation.confirmationAction = { [weak confirmation, weak self] response in
            guard let self = self else {
                return
            }

            var completedSignature: SignatureParameter?

            switch response {
            case let .signature(signature):
                completedSignature = signature
            case .discrepancy:
                break
            }

            let args = ["id": self.viewModel.id]
            let params = AcceptParameter(
                employee: self.viewModel.employee,
                signature: completedSignature,
                base64FuelSheet: self.sheet.ticket?.base64
            )

            if let confirm = confirmation {
                confirm.setLoading(true)

                API.client.post(.accept, with: args, using: .put, posting: params, expecting: Nothing.self, completion: { [weak self] (success, _) in
                    DispatchQueue.asyncMain {
                        guard let self = self else {
                            return
                        }

                        confirm.setLoading(false)
                            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) 
                        }
                    }
                })
                self.updateSheetVals()
            }
        }
        present(confirmation, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for sure:

```
case .success:
      DispatchQueue.asyncMain {
            let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: WarningViewController) as! WarningViewController
            self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and I had actually tried this but sadly it didn't work :(

Comment: Thanks again, actually I just played around with the placement of this bit of code and I moved it to make the second API call after the success is received from the first one... and that worked!

Comment: Great (Y) @DevB1

Answer (score 0):

For this

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

to work the vc must be inside a navigation controller and if not this `self.navigationController?` will be `nil` and nothing will show , you either need a segue/push.present like

```
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks - actually that part works :/ It's the controller that should be generated by the updateSheetVals() method that does nothing...